# Connect to 2 cassandra clusters in spring data

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to connect to 2 different cassandra clusters using spring data cassandra. But it always uses only the first cassandra cluster config. The second one is not taking affect. Any idea what am I doing wrong? This is the config that I am using:

First cassandra cluster config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = SourceRepository.class
)
public class SourceCassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getContactPoints() {
        return "localhost";
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return "9051";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "source_keyspace";
    }
}
```

Second cassandra cluster config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(
        basePackageClasses = TargetRepository.class,
        cassandraTemplateRef = "targetCassandraTemplate"
)
public class TargetCassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getContactPoints() {
        return "localhost";
    }

    @Override
    public int getPort() {
        return "9052";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "target_keyspace";
    }

    @Override
    @Bean("targetSession")
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = super.session();
        session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
        session.setCluster(cluster().getObject());
        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster = super.cluster();
        cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cluster.setPort(port);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean("targetCassandraTemplate")
    public CassandraAdminOperations cassandraTemplate(
            @Qualifier("targetSession") final CassandraSessionFactoryBean session) throws Exception {
        return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session.getObject(), cassandraConverter());
    }
}
```

I always see that only the first cluster node is getting added

```
com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster         : New Cassandra host localhost/127.0.0.1:9051 added
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I spent 2 days debugging this and 10 mins after posting this question, I found the fix :)

I wasn't using the cluster bean that I created properly in the session bean. So I did the following and it worked:

```
    @Override
    @Bean("targetCassandraCluster")
    public CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster() {
        CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster = super.cluster();
        cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cluster.setPort(port);
        return cluster;
    }

    @Bean("targetCassandraSession")
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session(
            @Qualifier("targetCassandraCluster") final CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean cluster
    ) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        final CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = super.session();
        session.setKeyspaceName(getKeyspaceName());
        session.setCluster(cluster.getObject());
        return session;
    }

    @Bean("targetCassandraTemplate")
    public CassandraAdminOperations cassandraTemplate(
            @Qualifier("targetCassandraSession") final CassandraSessionFactoryBean session) throws Exception {
        return new CassandraAdminTemplate(session.getObject(), cassandraConverter());
    }
```